# mysql binary field lookup using LIKE has a problem

Tags: mysql, binary, sql-like, ulid

I have a problem with BINARY(16) type (ULID under the hood) and specific ULID `01HRS49374C1EAGTPKTJ0JVT1P` (hex `018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836`) when queried using `LIKE`. LIKE query works with other ULIDs but not with this specific one.

Because its a ULID the length is always 16bytes so its not an issue with size of the field.

**Last `SELECT` statement from the code bellow returns empty result! Why?**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (
    id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO new_table SET id = UNHEX("018e321f579997e1f2a907a72b98f965"), name = "this works fine";
INSERT INTO new_table SET id = UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836"), name = "try find this using LIKE";

SELECT HEX(id), name FROM new_table WHERE id LIKE UNHEX("018e321f579997e1f2a907a72b98f965");
SELECT HEX(id), name FROM new_table WHERE id LIKE UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if we change the ESCAPE character:

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(id), name FROM new_table WHERE id LIKE UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836") ESCAPE '@';
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| HEX(id)                          | name                     |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 018E32448CE4605CA86AD3D4812DE836 | try find this using LIKE |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

It also works if we disable backslash as a metacharacter:

```
mysql> set sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT HEX(id), name FROM new_table WHERE id LIKE UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836");
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| HEX(id)                          | name                     |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 018E32448CE4605CA86AD3D4812DE836 | try find this using LIKE |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So I tried to view the binary string in the client:

```
% mysql --skip-binary-as-hex test

mysql> select UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836");
+-------------------------------------------+
| UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836") |
+-------------------------------------------+
| ?2D??`\?j?ԁ-?6                                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
        ^
```

There's the backslash.

The point being that `LIKE` applies some special meaning to certain characters in the string, like backslash and `_` and `%`.

If you UNHEX a random hex string, you don't know if the bytes will by coincidence become one of those characters that are special to `LIKE`.

Conclusion: It's not a bug.

`LIKE` is not the appropriate comparison operator for your search.

In your example, it would be fine to use `=`, because you are checking for strings being equal, not using pattern-matching with `LIKE`.

This works:

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(id), name FROM new_table WHERE id = UNHEX("018e32448ce4605ca86ad3d4812de836");
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| HEX(id)                          | name                     |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 018E32448CE4605CA86AD3D4812DE836 | try find this using LIKE |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------+
```